# AJAX script manager PageMethod not always called

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, webforms, code-behind

I have an AJAX call to a method in my code-behind. I have set everything up but it seems unreliable.

The java function uses PageMethods. to call my method in the code-behind. I have done some testing most times it works but sometimes for some reason it does not call the method in the code-behind.

I am not sure why it would not do it some times and can't see any patttern from the times it fails.

It is executed by clicking a link in a child window but you can keep clicking the same link and it will each time hit the method for X amount of times and then suddenly for one of them it won't do it.

The parent window AJAX call:

```
function Update(custtype) {
    PageMethods.CustType(custtype)
}
```

The child window that calls the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendval(value) {
        window.parent.onSave();
        window.parent.Update(value);
        window.top.document.getElementById('txtCustomerType').value = value;
        window.parent.location.reload()
        }
    </script>
```

The method in the parent window that for some reason is not always called:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string CustType(string custtype)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["CustType"] = "";
    HttpContext.Current.Session["CustType"] = custtype;
    return custtype;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a race-- the location.reload is tearing down the page along with the MS-Ajax infrastruture and finishing faster than the Update can finish calling. You have to put all subsequent code into the onSuccess callback or you will get races.

```
function sendval(value) {
   window.parent.onSave();
   window.parent.Update(value, onSuccess, /*onFailure*/);
   function onSuccess(result){
      window.top.document.getElementById('txtCustomerType').value = value;
      window.parent.location.reload()
    }
}
```